# How to reach bolt at the rear of BMW M41 Engine?

Tags: engine, bmw, stuck-bolt, screw

I can't manage to properly reach the top right screw (zoom picture of it on the second picture).

How could I do that ? (the tool I have is too long to be able to go on the rear, there is nearly no space !

Also, how to put the screw again without risking to loose it in the engine ? (I lost one screw in the engine this way !)

The place is nearly not reachable...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to remove this without taking off the piece above it? Its location suggests that it will be important to torque it back down correctly when reinstalling it. Even if you can get it off with a u-joint or flex-head ratchet, I don't think you'd be able to get a torque wrench in there.

Comment: What do you call the "piece above it" ? The tubes you see are precisely held by that bolt :(

Comment: Ah, gotcha. The tubes are exactly what I meant.

Comment: Definitely hard to tell over the internet ... I'd bet someone with some Bimmer experience might speak up. You may have to make yourself a tool to fit in there. I'd suggest getting a long handled box end wrench of the correct size, bend the end about 1.5" (4cm) from the head at 90deg, then bending it again about 5" (12cm) from the first bend at a 90deg angle opposite of the first one (so the top points away from the bolt). The idea is to create a handle which will give you enough torque to turn the bolt. It will only give you about 10-15deg of arc, but it's better than what's going on now.

Comment: I'm wondering why you want to remove this bolt. It looks like it is supposed to be removed after removing the intake manifold, which is a bit of a hassle (like having to replace the gasket). You may be able to remove it with either a box end or open end wrench. But, if there's not enough room, then you'll need to get an obstruction wrench. Sears and Home Depot are two places that sell them. As for avoiding dropping the bolt/screw, you can tape a magnet to a screwdriver and stick below the screw and/or stuff something around it so when it falls you can get it out.

Comment: For the screw, you can magnetize your screwdriver shaft to get it back in there.  The screw will just stay on the tip of the screwdriver like magic and won't fall off of it.

Answer (score 2):

As there is no mention of any special procedure to undo these bolts in the [TIS workshop manual](http://workshop-manuals.com/bmw/3_series_e36/318tds_m41_sal/2_repair_instructions/11__engine_%28m41%29/61__intake_manifold/1_ra__removing_and_installing_intake_air_manifold_%28m41%29/), I would use something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OVV0ZRM), a pivoting combination wrench/spanner:

[image: Flexible Ratchet Spanner]

The pivot should allow you to overcome the relative lack of space, while the ratcheting mechanism should save you oodles of time.

Comment: Downvoter, in your opinion what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: Hey, I was one of them, just saw this. Link only answer :)